# Change header of \listoftodos

Tags: todonotes

I use the todonotes package to highlight changes in a document and list them at the end of the document by the \listoftodos command. Instead of using the standard "Todo list" header, I'd like to call it something like "List of suggested changes". I have checked the package documentation for answers, but no luck so far. I am afraid it needs some redefining of commands that I am unable to do my self. Suggestions anyone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the optional argument of `\listoftodos`. See section "Options for the listoftodos command" in the package documentation of [`todonotes`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/todonotes).

```
\listoftodos[List of suggested changes]
```

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\begin{document}
Example text \todo{Dummy text} and more text
\listoftodos[List of suggested changes]
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, apparently I did not study the documentation well enough...